# Letters in phone numbers

Tags: code-golf, number

**Problem:**

You are making a new phone where people can type in specialized phone numbers, for example, `1-800-program`, and they would be converted automatically to a usable phone number, like `1-800-7764726` (for the previous example).

Your program will recieve a string if any length with numbers, letters and dashes, and convert all the letters to their corresponding numbers.

Here is a keypad, for reference:

[image: keypad]

**Rules:**

- Your program will receive a string
- It will process it and return/print another string
- Any language is accepted
- Since it is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code wins

Comment: Should the program handle both upper and lower case letters in the input?

Comment: @mattnewport - no, assume the variable has been turned into lowercase already

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## GolfScript, 24 chars

```
{.96>{,91,'qx'+-,3/`}*}%
```

Test input:

```
0123456789-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Test output:

```
0123456789-22233344455566677778889999
```

Explanation:

- `{ }%` applies the code between the braces to each character of the input.
- `.96>{ }*` executes the code between the inner braces if and only if the ASCII code of the character is greater than 96 (i.e. it is a lowercase letter).
- The first `,` turns the character into a list of all characters with lower ASCII codes, and `91,'qx'+-` filters out all characters with ASCII codes less than 91, as well as the letters `q` and `x`, from the list.
  Thus, for example, the character `a` gets turned into the 6-character list `` [\]^_` ``, while `z` gets turned into the 29-character list `` [\]^_`abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwy ``.
- The second `,` counts the elements remaining in the list, and `3/` divides this count by three (rounding down).  Finally, the `` ` `` turns the resulting number (in the range 2 – 9) into a string.

Thus, as per spec, hyphens and numbers are left unchanged, while lowercase letters are mapped into numbers according to the reference keypad diagram.  The code will actually cleanly pass through all printable ASCII characters except for lowercase letters (which as mapped as described) and the characters `{`, `|` and `}` (which are mapped to the two-character string `10`).  Non-ASCII 8-bit input will produce all sorts of weird numeric output.

After all this, it's a bit disappointing that this only beats the [trivial bash solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21331) by just six chars.

Answer (score 51):

### Bash, 30

Edit: Thank you Doorknob for eliminating 3 chars

```
tr a-z 22233344455566677778889
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Can't you remove the last 3 `9`s?

Answer (score 16):

## C, <s>83</s> <s>78</s> <s>77</s> <s>65</s> <s>63</s> 62

```c
main(c){for(;~(c=getchar());putchar(c>96?20-c/122+5*c/16:c));}
```

http://ideone.com/qMsIFQ

Comment: Nice math. Just wanna say that you can reduce 1 char by assuming EOF is -1 and do `~(c=getchar())`

Comment: Couldn't you use `getch()` instead of `getchar()`?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `getch()` isn't standard C, as a result I guess it doesn't link in ideone. I tested it in MSVC anyway though and it doesn't really work sadly - as it directly consumes keyboard input there's no way to exit the program, although it does translate what you type on the fly which is kind of neat.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript - 103 characters

```javascript
alert(prompt().replace(/[a-z]/g,function(y){y=y.charCodeAt(0)-91;return y>27?9:y>24?8:y>20?7:~~(y/3)}))
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that with .replace. Up vote for you!

Comment: You can replace `charCodeAt(0)` with `charCodeAt()` and you can use arrow function for `function(y)...` to save few bytes and for `~~(y/3)` you can use `y/3|0`

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 75 chars

```
gets.chars{|c|$><<"22233344455566677778889999#{c}"[[*?a..?z].index(c)||-1]}
```

Uses the deprecated `chars` with block, and prints each letter individually with `$><<`. I also like `[[*?a..?z].index(c)||-1]`; it grabs the character corresponding to that letter of the alphabet if it's a letter, and the last character (which happens to be the test character unchanged) if not.

## Ruby, 43 (or 35) chars

Blatantly stealing from @ace ;)

```
puts gets.tr'a-z','22233344455566677778889'
```

Shave off 8 chars if I can run in IRB with the variable `s` as the string:

```
s.tr'a-z','22233344455566677778889'
```

Answer (score 3):

## C++ - 222 chars

Longest solution so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#define o std::cout<<
int main(){std::string s;std::cin>>s;for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){int j=s[i]-97;if(j<0)o s[i];if(0<=j&j<15)o 2+j/3;if(14<j&j<19)o 7;if(18<j&j<22)o 8;if(21<j&j<26)o 9;}}
```

Comment: Lol, I don't think longest solution is the goal here...

Comment: @Danny C++ does not lend itself well to [tag:code-golf].  Java and C# are the only languages that are worse, that I know of (all the classes, object creation, and long names for output...).

Comment: I know, I just thought it was funny that you mentioned "Longest solution".

Answer (score 3):

## Frink, 92

A rather verbose language, I know. This checks 8 values instead of 26 without having to type out the compares. Can any of the above "222333444.." solutions be reduced in a similar way?

Using built in structures, 107

```
co=new OrderedList
co.insertAll[charList["cfilosv{"]]
println[input[""]=~%s/([a-z])/co.binarySearch[$1]+2/eg]
```

Using a custom recursive function, 92

```
fn[x,a]:=x<=(charList["cfilosv{"])@a?a+2:fn[x,a+1]
println[input[""]=~%s/([a-z])/fn[$1,0]/eg]
```

Comment: +1 for reducing the string-translation method to an 8-character search. Nice touch.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2.7, <strike>66</strike> 65

#### Anakata's Original

```
for c in raw_input():print'\b'+(`(ord(c)-97)/3+2-(c in('svyz'))`if c>'`'else c),
```

#### Further golfed

```
for c in input():print(ord(c)-91)/3-(c in('svyz'))if c>'`'else c,
```

I don't have enough reputation to comment on @anakata's answer, so I made a separate post here. I had the same idea (taking the ordinance modulus 3) but couldn't figure out how to print the right numbers for *s - z*.

Anyways, the golf improvements I made:

- changed `raw_input` to `input`
- removed the extraneous `'\b'` and parentheses and single quotes
- removed the `+2` offset and placed that in the original subtraction (97 - (3 * 2) = 91)

*Tested with the Python 2.7.6 interpreter. Assumes, per the rules, a string input.*

Comment: you could also remove the space between the ) and the if

Comment: You're right. good catch willem

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <strike>49</strike> 48 bytes

```scala
_.map(c=>if(c>96)(c/3.2+20).toChar min'9'else c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VczPasJAEMfxu08xeHGXMnEb658IBkpPQilCH6Bs1omJJps1u1Zb8dnj5CJ4m4Hv5@eNrnTXZHsyAT4pBGr92m6KxtLXqc74A7oEslsP787BdQCwpRzyJXyHtrQ7WKWPq/uJau2EWaVlLkyazKQw40kUv8RKRqH5KHQLdWlHyYgqT2BkB@CYhsqKXAx1Znh6V5T7Q1Xbxh1bH06/58vf/1DKwVOqlELOkXtkgCyQCfYGGWGvUCWL@Wz6Nolf@4Fbdwc)

Maps `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` to `22233344455566677778889999` via `(c/3.2+20).toChar min'9'`

(saved 1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen)

Comment: You can remove the space at `min'9'` for -1.

Answer (score 2):

## Smalltalk, <strike>79</strike> 70

input is s:

```
s collect:[:c|' 22233344455566677778889999'at:1put:c;at:(($ato:$z)indexOf:c)+1]
```

probably not a candidate for being shortest - but may be of interest for an old trick to avoid a test for a not-found condition (indexOf: returns 0 in this case).  So no special test for letters is needed. Some Smalltalks however, have immutable strings, and we need 4 more chars ("copy").

Oh, a better version, which even deals with immutable strings in 70 chars:

```
s collect:[:c|c,'22233344455566677778889999'at:(($ato:$z)indexOf:c)+1]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 90

This follows the logic of @ace's solution:

```
StringReplace[#,Thread[CharacterRange["A","Z"]->Characters@"22233344455566677778889999"]]&
```

Example

```
StringReplace[#1,Thread[CharacterRange["A","Z"]-> 
Characters@"22233344455566677778889999"]]&["VI37889"]
```

> 8437889

Comment: Your arrow character representation isn't accepted by Mma in a copy/paste

Comment: Also,you don't need the `1` in `#1`:)

Comment: Belisarius, I changed the arrow back and removed the `1`.  Still 90 char but cut and paste will work. You understand of course the motivation to use the single char arrow.

Comment: Been there, done that :)

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 50

Another obvious copy of Ace's bash answer

```
($_)=@ARGV;y/a-z/22233344455566677778889999/;print
```

Comment: This code is working correctly but there's room for improvement. Let's get rid of $ARGV[0] and use `-p` switch instead which lets you nicely go through each line of stdin.  While we're at it, the range in y/// doesn't need to be put in square brackets. We can also get rid of three 9's leaving just one and remove the final semi-colon:

    `-p y/a-z/22233344455566677778889/`
 
There you go, 30 + 1 for `-p`. Thank you for using Enterprise Chinese Perl Golfing and Optimization Services and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 141

Not the shortest, but more fun:

```
<?php foreach(str_split($argv[1])as$c){$v=ord($c);if($v>114){$v--;}if($v==121){$v--;}if($v<123&$v>96){echo chr(ceil($v/3+17));}else{echo$c;}}
```

More readable:

```
<?php 
foreach (str_split($argv[1]) as $c) {
  $v=ord($c);
  if ($v>114) {$v--;}
  if ($v==121){$v--;}
  if ($v<123 & $v>96){
    echo chr(ceil($v/3+17));
    } else {echo $c;}
}
```

Comment: OP said that the input is already in lowercase, so you can remove the `strtolower`

Answer (score 2):

### R, very long but fun

```
foo <- '1-800-splurghazquieaobuer57'
oof <- unlist(strsplit(foo,''))
#don't count that part - it's input formatting :-) 
digout <- unlist(strsplit('22233344455566677778889999','')) 
oof[oof%in%letters[1:26]] <- unlist(sapply(oof[oof%in%letters[1:26]], function(j) digout[which(letters[1:26]==j)] ))
```

Answer (score 2):

## k [32 Chars]

```
{(.Q.a!|,/(4 3 4,5#3)#'|$2+!8)x}
```

#### Usage

```
{(.Q.a!|,/(4 3 4,5#3)#'|$2+!8)x}"stack exchange"
"78225 39242643"
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 85

JavaScript is never going to win the golf wars, but I like it and I wanted to do something different than jump on the @ace bandwagon.

```
alert(prompt().replace(/[a-z]/g,function(a){for(i=7;a<"dgjmptw{"[i--];);return i+4}))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python 2.7, 80**

```
for c in raw_input():print'\b'+(`(ord(c)-97)/3+2-(c in('svyz'))`if c>'`'else c),
```

I am new to python, so **I'm sure there must be a way to golf this even further**, it's a different aproach, hope you guys like it, ***my god, is python pretty!***

Run example:

- input:  01-800-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
- output: 01-800-22233344455566677778889999

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 216 bytes

I spent quite some time over the past couple of nights painstakingly creating a mathematical sequence function that would round correctly to generate the proper ASCII codes for the numbers from the alphabetical ASCII codes. It had a ridiculous number of decimal places in the coefficients, but it worked.

However, mattnewport's rational approach works in SQL as well, at a much lower cost of bytes, so I am shamelessly scrapping my own math in favor of his. Go up-vote him, it's an elegant solution!

Here's mine:

```
DECLARE @p VARCHAR(MAX)='';WITH t AS(SELECT ASCII(LEFT(@s,1))c,2 i UNION ALL SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(@s,i,1)),i+1FROM t WHERE i<=LEN(@s))SELECT @p=@p+CHAR(CASE WHEN c>96THEN 20-c/122+5*c/16 ELSE c END)FROM t;SELECT @p
```

This uses a recursive CTE to make an impromptu stack of the characters in the phone number and translate the letters on the fly, then a bit of SQL trickery (SELECT @p=@p+columnValue) to recompose the string from the CTE without requiring another recursion construct.

Output:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX)='1-800-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
--above code runs here
1-800-22233344455566677778889999
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
Aā6+žq÷T9:‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8UijmfbRfYWHt4dYWj1qWPj/v4GhkbGJqZm5haVuYlJySmpaekZmVnZObl5@QWFRcUlpWXlFZRUA)

```
A                 # alphabet: "abcdefghijklmnoqrstuvwxyz"
 ā                # length range: [1..26]
  6+              # add 6 to each: [7..32]
    žq÷           # divide by pi: [2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,10]
       T9:        # replace 10 with 9
          ‡       # transliterate the input (a => 2, ..., z => 9)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 14 bytes

```
ka:ż6+kiḭṪ9JṅĿ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJrYTrFvDYra2nhuK3huao5SuG5hcS/IiwiIiwiMDEyMzQ1Njc4OS1hYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5eiJd)

```
ka:ż6+kiḭṪ9JṅĿ
ka:            # Push the alphabet twice
   ż           # Length range: [1..26]
    6+         # Add 6: [7..32]
      kiḭ      # Floor divide by pi: [2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,10]
         Ṫ9J   # Remove the last item and append 10
            ṅ  # Join by nothing to make a string
             Ŀ # Transliterate the input from the alphabet to this
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 87

```
echo str_ireplace(range('a','z'),str_split('22233344455566677778889999'),fgets(STDIN));
```

Answer (score 1):

## q [38 Chars]

```
{(.Q.a!"22233344455566677778889999")x}
```

Inspired by @ace's solution

Example

```
{(.Q.a!"22233344455566677778889999")x}"stack exchange"
"78225 39242643"
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# 140

```c#
using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(string[]a){System.Console.Write(string.Concat(a[0].Select(d=>(char)(d>96?20-d/122+5*d/16:d))));}}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### XQuery, 71

[BaseX](http://basex.org) was used as XQuery processor. `$i` is input.

```
translate($i,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz","22233344455566677778889999")
```

Not the shortest answer, but quite short and very readable.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, very ungolfed

Since everyone is copying ace, i decided to post the code i made up before i submitted the question:

```
def phonekeypad(text):
    c = ['','','abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqrs','tuv','wxyz']
    st = ""
    for i in list(text):
        a = False
        for t in range(len(c)):
            if i in c[t]:
                st += str(t)
                a=True
        if a == False:
            st += str(i)
    return st
```

Answer (score 1):

## EcmaScript 6 (103 bytes):

```
i.replace(/[a-z]/g,x=>keys(a='00abc0def0ghi0jkl0mno0pqrs0tuv0wxyz'.split(0)).find(X=>a[X].contains(x)))
```

*Expects `i` to contain the string.*

Try it in any recent version of Firefox. I've not tried Google Chrome.

Comment: You can replace `split(0)` with `split\`0\``

Comment: @LeoDog896 True, but that doesn't save any bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 121

```
print("".join((lambda x:"22233344455566677778889999"[ord(x)-97] if ord(x)>96 and ord(x)<123 else x)(i) for i in input()))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 93C

```
t[]_ a=a
t(b:c)(d:e)a
 |a==b=d
 |True=t c e a
y=map(t['a'..'z']"22233344455566677778889999")
```

Usage

```
y "1-800-program"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 54

```
print map{/[a-y]/?int(5/16*ord)-28:/z/?9:$_}<>=~/./gs
```

Shoot, @RobHoare still beat me by 4 characters. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 50 bytes

```cpp
[](auto&s){for(auto&c:s)c=c>96?20-c/122+5*c/16:c;}
```

this is a port of [mattnewport's C solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21349/112488).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7dCoJAFISvPU@xEIQWkgpJqW0P4WV0sRw3WXB/2D0GET27KUJ0NTMMwzfoXIqDMP1EUrtBkGzo5aQRWrKWQ8tIBopbFhJ4T7d7LEay25C8H9avHquQ4AX5ubwWWYqHvCj2x92sZYX1Z4rikNQQeUmjNyzU8AHYKIPD2EnWKBvIS6E5gDIEWigTP63qZhhEgbqqmntl@mW4ZlSGcf6X7UisadabC@rHymbWlKenLEudt70X@gs)

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
import string          
trans = str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase,
                      '22233344455566677778889999')                                                                                         
print("1-800-ask-usps".translate(trans))
```

Answer (score 0):

**ECMASCRIPT, 101 (with input)**

```
"1-800-PROGRAM".replace(/./g,function(c){
return "22233344455566677778889999"[c.charCodeAt(0)-65]||c})
```

Newline added for clarity.  85 characters if the input is in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

## QBasic, 155

Ah, the memories...

```
INPUT n$
FOR i=1 TO LEN(n$)
c$=MID$(n$,i,1)
a=ASC(c$)
IF 97>a THEN
PRINT c$;
ELSE IF 122>a THEN
PRINT STR$(a\3.2-28);
ELSE
PRINT 9;
END IF
NEXT i
```

This should have been shorter, but I was testing with [repl.it](http://repl.it), which doesn't allow single-line `IF` statements and behaves strangely if you leave the variable off of `NEXT i`.  It also doesn't recognize the `ASC` function, so to run the code you'll need to add this workaround at the beginning:

```
DECLARE FUNCTION ASC(s$)
FUNCTION ASC(s$)
FOR j=1 TO 255
IF CHR$(j)=LEFT$(s$,1) THEN
ASC=j
END IF
NEXT j
END FUNCTION
```

(The second time you run it, the interpreter will complain unless you remove the `DECLARE FUNCTION` line, go figure.)

Answer (score 0):

### R, 110

```
s=strsplit(scan(,""),"")[[1]];i=grep("[a-z]",s);s[i]=sort(c(1:24%%8+2,7,9))[match(s[i],letters)];cat(s,sep="")
```

Example:

```
> s=strsplit(scan(,""),"")[[1]];i=grep("[a-z]",s);s[i]=sort(c(1:24%%8+2,7,9))[match(s[i],letters)];cat(s,sep="")
1: 1-800-program
2: 
Read 1 item
1-800-7764726
```

Answer (score 0):

### VB.net (61c)

*Excludes the 45c min for a valid vb.net program*.

```
Module P
Sub Main(A()As string)
For Each x In A(0).ToUpper 
Console.Write(If(x<"A"or x>"Z",x,Chr(Asc(x)\4+35)))
Next
End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 196 bytes

```rust
x.iter().map(|x|match x{'a'|'b'|'c'=>'2','d'|'e'|'f'=>'3','g'|'h'|'i'=>'4','j'|'k'|'l'=>'5','m'|'n'|'o'=>'6','p'|'q'|'r'|'s'=>'7','t'|'u'|'v'=>'8','w'|'x'|'y'|'z'=>'9',_=>*x}).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDLboMwEEX3fIWTjaGiUd8PCEj9gi4qdVNFETUOcWsMdRzqFvLt9E4UpV12ca58j0D2jN1u3LgyrC6UCaM@0NIxzzLWSTF54ec8ZvyU4o7i7Bh711JYHvOGDtWhMV5Q1HyRBq1VxmkzCaePVlXKFJolrN9NYz9TTtowmgndGFnSodFaCpck8yeHv6o8jKI02L@ny8bj93XRhoMf6sKJNfM97hr4KxA8y/kF3lKiSLAicQlRoayBInEF8YbyDjSJa4gaxYCGxA1Ei/IBLNiQvIV0KFvQkcA6@CeKB1/gm@Q9j5dZfuJ3f6d5lmK@zDFNOv5u40FjGlmywza6f25jF4w/)

Power of `match`. Yet match for every letter feels unnecessarily tedious. Still trying to grasp `iter()` and subsequent functions

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 326 bytes

```
,[>+[-[---<]>>-]<--<<<[>>>>+<[->[-]>+<<]>[-<<+>>]>[-<<+>>]<<-<<+<-]+>>[<<->[-]>->[<+>+]<->>+++++[>+++++<-]>[<+>-]+<<<[>>-<+<-]>[<+>-]>[>-<[-]]>[<<<->>>-]++++[>++++<-]>+<<<<[>>+>>[-<<[-]>+>]<<[-<+>]>[->+<]>-<<<<<+>-]>>>>[-]<<<[<<->>-]<+++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]>[-]+++++[>++++++++++<-]>.[-]<<]<<[->.>>[-]<<<]>[-]<,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/ZDsIwDPugEsR9SFF@JOrDOAZj3DCunx9OyrFKW@PGdpzZOSv2eTUv67qlEpSUiDiKUGQUzCo4gZVEKaJAT/EeRP4FsxVMEUABnIo/mgE20NvRdIHmHbCTPXHjTRQYcsPmZEH@Yk4RXGazMNZTWQSA4JnAwHRjJUcxYjSRG6I0J/BIJa0RPtq0C6cd/WsG/6Vvu52PlPbX3OncinXd6fb6g@FoPJlSNpsvlvlqXWzK7W5/OJ7Ol2t1uz@erzc)

For each character:

- Check if it's a letter. If not, print it and go to the next character.
- Check if it's 'z'. If it is, subtract 1 to make it 'y'
- Check if it's after 'r'. If it is, subtract 1 to realign it with the number grid.
- Divide the letter number by 3.
- Add the result to 50 ('2') and print it.

```
stage0 memory layout:
| input x | input backup | compare result z | compare val y | compare t0 | compare t1 |
stage1:
| else flag | input backup | prev compare result / letter index y | inv letter index / compare t0 | compare t1 | compare val x |
stage2:
| else flag | letter index backup | letter index x | compare result z | compare t0 | compare t1 | compare val y |

,[ Read first character
    >+[-[---<]>>-]<-- Check if input is greater than 96 (a lowercase letter)
    <<<[>>>>+
        <[->[-]>+<<]
        >[-<<+>>]
        >[-<<+>>]
        <<-<<+<-
    ]
    
    + Set else flag
    >>[ If input is a letter:
        ((stage1))
        <<->[-]>- Clear the result/else flags
        >[<+>+]<- Invert the letter index

        >>+++++[>+++++<-]> Check if letter 25 (z)
        [<+>-]+
        <<<[>>-<+<-]
        >[<+>-]
        >[>-<[-]]
        >[<<<->>>-] If it is subtract 1 to change it to y

        ((stage2))
        ++++[>++++<-]>+ Check if greater than letter 17 (r)
        <<<<[>>+
            >>[-<<[-]>+>]
            <<[-<+>]
            >[->+<]
            >-<<<<<+>-
        ]
        >>>>[-] Clear y
        <<<[<<->>-] If it is subtract 1 to normalize indices
        <+++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<] Divide normalized index by 3
        >[-]>[-] Clear tempvars from division
        +++++[>++++++++++<-]>. Add 50 ('2') to result and print it
        [-]<< Clear letter index

        ((stage0))
    ]<<[ If input isn't a letter:
        - Clear the result flag
        >. Just print the character
        >>[-]<<< Clear the letter index
    ]
    >[-]<, Next input
]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 27 bytes

```
T`l`22233344455566677778889
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/PyQhJ8HIyMjY2NjExMTU1NTMzMwcCCwsLCz//zfUtTAw0C0oyk8vSszVraisAgA)

Port of the Bash solution. `T`ransliterates each `l`owercase letter to a digit between `2` and `9`. The list is implicitly padded with 3 additional `9`s

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 80 bytes

```hs
d c|elem c['a'..'z']="22233344455566677778889999"!!(fromEnum c-97)|1>0=c
l=map d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcsxDsIgFADQ3VP8EhN0oKFQKB1wc3NzNA6E1mgEbIDGxPTuyNvf06T37FwpE9htdrMHe8MGty3@4btGjDHOed/3Qggp5VAppcYKNc3hET/@HNZ6yDgct@5Etd057c0CU/HmFUDDsuZrjpcAe3CAOqIoJSmbCF8TEyp/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ạż6+kP÷T9vṆ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCQSVBMCVDNSVCQzYlMkJrUCVDMyVCN1Q5diVFMSVCOSU4NiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTEtODAwLXByb2dyYW0mZmxhZ3M9ZQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
Ạż6+kP÷T9vṆ  # Implicit input
Ạ            # Push the lowercase alphabet
 ż           # Without popping, push [1..26]
  6+         # Add 6 to make it [7..26]
    kP÷      # Floor divide each by pi
       T9v   # Replace the 10 with a 9
          Ṇ  # Transliterate the input
             # Implicit output
```

Answer (score -1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 130 bytes

```python
d=lambda x:str(int((ord(x)-96)*.31769+1.76715))
def f(s,c=''):
	for i in s:c+=(d(i)if i!='z'else'9')if i.isalpha()else i
	print(c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc1BDoMgEADAs76Cnna3ViMxajXhMVSkbqJCwIPt52nsdS7jP8fi9iYlo1a9vYwW5xiPgLwfiC4YPKkcOrpXjey7oZBV3/WyJcrNbIXF@JgUAI15Zl0QLHgXcZwKhQaZ2Aq@KfjCvMYZBvhDxVGvftFIlwrOMx@ubKJkEWT5rOvSB/cOegNKPw)

Uses the formula `y = (x * .31769) + 1.76715` to approximate the given relation. Sadly this formula gives wring value for `z` hence requires one additional check

Comment: [80](https://tio.run/##PctJDoIwGEDhvaforq3aQkUZTDyJuihi4Uc6WHBAwtmrK3cv@fLcODTWJEEdTqGTuqwk6vcY89aCIQpPME/6V8T6igBlRUqXPBHZSvAsXRc0isSMj8Chl51rJKFnZT0CBAb1NDgPZiCKYMHyOGbO29pLjSld/CUWm2S7S7O8YLK8VFdVN9DeOm2su/t@eDxf7/HzO8IX)

Comment: [65](https://tio.run/##PctLDsIgFADAvadgB5hASlGpJp5EXVAr7esHEOqnNj07unI9GT@NjbMymeM59XooK43iAWPeOrDE4BmW2YWKAF1zKRTLC64WfAIOUfe@0YRejAsIEFgUafIB7EgMwYIVWcZ8cHXQA6Z09ZdM5HKz3aliz3R5rW6mbqDt@sE6fw9xfDxf7@nzG@kL) based on the above