# Generate the python dictionary of phone keypresses for any letter

Tags: code-golf, data-structures

In the fewest bytes, generate the dictionary of keypresses for any letter (as described in https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p2)

In Python, the dictionary literal itself:

```
{'a':2,'c':222,'b':22,'e':33,'d':3,'g':4,'f':333,'i':444,'h':44,'k':55,'j':5,'m':6,'l':555,'o':666,'n':66,'q':77,'p':7,'s':7777,'r':777,'u':88,'t':8,'w':9,'v':888,'y':999,'x':99,'z':9999}
```

is 187 bytes so it needs to be less than that.  (The values can be strings or ints, ie you can have 'a':'2' or 'a':2 it's up to you)

NOTE: This is not asking you to solve the referenced GCJ problem, it's just asking you to generate a particular dictionary which is related to that problem.

EDIT: You may solve this in any language which has a dictionary-like type (ie hashmap, associative array etc.)

Comment: Do we have to solve this in Python, or can we use any language to generate and output the dictionary literal?

Comment: I guess any language.  Let me fix that

Comment: Also, looks like the GCJ problem itself [has been asked here before](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22875/phone-multi-tap-spelling).

Comment: Huh, I should have checked that first.  I posted this because we were talking about how to generate this dictionary (in Python) on #gcj on Freenode

Comment: Order doesn't matter?

Comment: You should be using an unordered data-type.  This problem isn't to "output" the result, it's to "generate" it

Comment: Do all values have to be the same type? ex:`{a:2,b:"22"...}` and do the dictionary keys have to be lowercase letters?

Comment: Is the idea to store it in a variable or to print a correctly-formatted dict literal? The latter seems more interesting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## perl, <strike>49</strike> 48 bytes

Using a different algorithm than my previous answer, we can lose another 12 bytes. The basic idea is that you usually just add the digit from the last letter's solution over again. We handle the other cases (detected by a short regex) by starting with a single instance of the last digit + 1.

```
{map{$d++,$t=""if/[dgjmptw]/;$_,$t.=$d||=2}a..z}
```

With output:

```
ski@anito:~/src$ perl -MData::Dumper  -e '$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1; $d=2;print Dumper {map{$d++,$t=""if/[dgjmptw]/;$_,$t.=$d}a..z}'
$VAR1 = {
      'a' => '2',
      'b' => '22',
      'c' => '222',
      'd' => '3',
      'e' => '33',
      'f' => '333',
      'g' => '4',
      'h' => '44',
      'i' => '444',
      'j' => '5',
      'k' => '55',
      'l' => '555',
      'm' => '6',
      'n' => '66',
      'o' => '666',
      'p' => '7',
      'q' => '77',
      'r' => '777',
      's' => '7777',
      't' => '8',
      'u' => '88',
      'v' => '888',
      'w' => '9',
      'x' => '99',
      'y' => '999',
      'z' => '9999'
};
```

Comment: Woo! Suck it J and Golfscript. Perl 4 eva! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

## Python (83)<strike>(87)</strike>

```python
c,d=97,{}
for i in range(2,10):
 for j in range(1,4+(i>6)*i%2):d[chr(c)],c=j*str(i),c+1
```

The dictionary is stored in `d`. The condition check `(i>6)*i%2` saves two chars from `(i in[7,9])`.

### Edit:

```python
c=97;d={}
for i in range(8):
 for j in range(1,4+(i|2>6)):d[chr(c)]=j*str(i+2);c+=1
```

Shaved 4 characters. With `i` shifted down by 2, we recognize the special cases of 7 and 9 by checking if `i` is 5 or 7 using `i|2>6`.

Comment: (6<i<10) saves another character.

Comment: @isaacg but it includes 8...

Answer (score 3):

## Golfscript, 68 characters

```
"{'"26,{.[.",'"''if\97+"':"]''+\..11-
7/.0>*-.3/2[+]\3%)@18=+*}/"9}"
```

What's this, you say? [It outputs the correct Python dict literal](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=InsnIjI2LHsuWy4iLCciMGlmXDk3KyInOiJdJycrXC4uMTEtCjcvLjA%2BKi0uMy8yWytdXDMlKUAxOD0rKn0vIjl9Ig%3D%3D):

```
{'a':2,'b':22,'c':222,'d':3,'e':33,'f':333,'g':4,'h':44,'i':444,'j':5,'k':55,'l':555,'m':6,'n':66,'o':666,'p':7,'q':77,'r':777,'s':7777,'t':8,'u':88,'v':888,'w':9,'x':99,'y':999,'z':9999}
```

That is,

```
$ echo print `ruby golfscript.rb phonetyp.gs` | python
{'a': 2, 'c': 222, 'b': 22, 'e': 33, 'd': 3, 'g': 4, 'f': 333, 'i': 444, 'h': 44, 'k': 55, 'j': 5, 'm': 6, 'l': 555, 'o': 666, 'n': 66, 'q': 77, 'p': 7, 's': 7777, 'r': 777, 'u': 88, 't': 8, 'w': 9, 'v': 888, 'y': 999, 'x': 99, 'z': 9999}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 86 characters

Alternate Python solution:

```
d={}
for a in range(26):n=a-max(0,(a-11)/7);d[chr(a+97)]=`n/3+2`*(n%3+1+(a in(18,25)))
```

Comment: For this range `max(0,(a-11)/7)` = `max(0,a-11)/7` = `a/18-a/25`. You can squeeze 2 or even 6 more bytes ;)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (*ES5*) <strike>88</strike> <strike>86</strike> 85 bytes

```javascript
for(o={},a=c=2,b=96;a-10;a=a<(c%9%7?b:1e3)?a+[c]:++c)o[String.fromCharCode(++b)]=+a;o
```

**Result:**

```javascript
{"a":2,"b":22,"c":222,"d":3,"e":33,"f":333,"g":4,"h":44,"i":444,"j":5,"k":55,"l":555,"m":6,"n":66,"o":666,"p":7,"q":77,"r":777,"s":7777,"t":8,"u":88,"v":888,"w":9,"x":99,"y":999,"z":9999}
```

If mixed types are allowed, it can be reduced by 1 byte.

## <strike>86</strike> 84 bytes:

```javascript
for(o={},a=c=2,b=96;a-10;a=a<(c%9%7?b:1e3)?a+[c]:++c)o[String.fromCharCode(++b)]=a;o
```

**Result:**

```javascript
{"a":2,"b":"22","c":"222","d":3,"e":"33","f":"333","g":4,"h":"44","i":"444","j":5,"k":"55","l":"555","m":6,"n":"66","o":"666","p":7,"q":"77","r":"777","s":"7777","t":8,"u":"88","v":"888","w":9,"x":"99","y":"999","z":"9999"}
```

Answer (score 1):

## perl, 61 bytes

Examine the mod3 and div3 of a counter $t to determine the base digit and number of repetitions. Handle the special cases of s and z separately.

```
$t=5;{map{$b=++$t%3+1;$b=4,--$t if/s|z/;$_,int($t/3)x$b}a..z}
```

With string output:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -e '$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1; $t=5;print Dumper {map{$b=++$t%3+1;$b=4,--$t if/s|z/;$_,int($t/3)x$b}a..z}' 
$VAR1 = {
      'a' => '2',
      'b' => '22',
      'c' => '222',
      'd' => '3',
      'e' => '33',
      'f' => '333',
      'g' => '4',
      'h' => '44',
      'i' => '444',
      'j' => '5',
      'k' => '55',
      'l' => '555',
      'm' => '6',
      'n' => '66',
      'o' => '666',
      'p' => '7',
      'q' => '77',
      'r' => '777',
      's' => '7777',
      't' => '8',
      'u' => '88',
      'v' => '888',
      'w' => '9',
      'x' => '99',
      'y' => '999',
      'z' => '9999'
    };
```

And here's a more readable version of the code:

```
{
  map {
    my $reps = (++$pos % 3) + 1;
    if($_ =~ /s|z/) {
      --$pos;
      $reps=4;
    }
    my $digit = int( $pos/3 );
    $_ => $digit x $reps
  } ('a'..'z')
}
```

We start with $pos = 5 so that int(++$pos/3) starts off at 2.

We handle the case of s and z separately since they are the only exceptions to the modulo 3 rule.

Answer (score 1):

## J - 57 char

The closest analogue to the dictionary datatype in J is a table of boxes: each row is an entry, containing the key on the left and the data on the right. It's not really unordered, but whenever you need a dictionary type of record, you would use something like this.

```
_2]\;n(;&.><\)/@|:/.n,.~u:97+i.#n=.,":"0(#~3+e.&7 9)2+i.8
```

`n` is the string `'22233344455566677778889999'`, which we create by taking the list `2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` and taking three of 4 of each element, depending on whether the element is 7 or 9. Then we just convert each item to a string and run them together into a single string.

Then we make the alphabet, attach the digits to the alphabet with `,.~`, and then group them by the digits (this is `/.` at work). Within each group, we pair off the letter with the corresponding prefix of the string of same digits.

Finally, we run things together: `;` to take off the effects of the earlier grouping and `_2]\` to put it into the proper table shape.

```
   _2]\;n(;&.><\)/@|:/.n,.~u:97+i.#n=.,":"0(#~3+e.&7 9)2+i.8
+-+----+
|a|2   |
+-+----+
|b|22  |
+-+----+
|c|222 |
+-+----+
|d|3   |
+-+----+
|e|33  |
+-+----+
|f|333 |
+-+----+
|g|4   |
+-+----+
|h|44  |
+-+----+
|i|444 |
+-+----+
|j|5   |
+-+----+
|k|55  |
+-+----+
|l|555 |
+-+----+
|m|6   |
+-+----+
|n|66  |
+-+----+
|o|666 |
+-+----+
|p|7   |
+-+----+
|q|77  |
+-+----+
|r|777 |
+-+----+
|s|7777|
+-+----+
|t|8   |
+-+----+
|u|88  |
+-+----+
|v|888 |
+-+----+
|w|9   |
+-+----+
|x|99  |
+-+----+
|y|999 |
+-+----+
|z|9999|
+-+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 168

This is the longest answer here... I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

```
(k=#2[[1]]+1;Append[{},{#->StringJoin@ConstantArray[ToString@k,#2]}]&~MapIndexed~#)&~MapIndexed~Characters@{"abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"}~Flatten~3
```

Output:

```
{"a" -> "2", "b" -> "22", "c" -> "222", "d" -> "3", "e" -> "33", 
"f" -> "333", "g" -> "4", "h" -> "44", "i" -> "444", "j" -> "5", 
"k" -> "55", "l" -> "555", "m" -> "6", "n" -> "66", "o" -> "666", 
"p" -> "7", "q" -> "77", "r" -> "777", "s" -> "7777", "t" -> "8", 
"u" -> "88", "v" -> "888", "w" -> "9", "x" -> "99", "y" -> "999", 
"z" -> "9999"}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash + coreutils, 91 bytes

```
p="printf %s\n"
paste <($p {a..z}) <($p {2..9} {22..99..11} {222..999..111} 7777 9999|sort)
```

Generates a tab-delimited table, which is a natural structure for a shell script - not sure if that meets the specs or not:

```
a   2
b   22
c   222
d   3
...
r   777
s   7777
t   8
u   88
v   888
w   9
x   99
y   999
z   9999
```

---

## Pure Bash, 137 bytes

Not very good.

```
declare -A a
b=({X..z})
for n in {9..33};do
c=${b[n]}
((n>26?n--:n))
printf -vk %$[n%3+1]s
a[$c]=${k// /$[n/3-1]}
done
a[s]+=7
a[z]=9999
```

This populates a bash associative array.

Crudely display it as follows:

```
$ for c in ${!a[@]}; do echo -n $c:${a[$c]},;done; echo
a:2,b:22,c:222,d:3,e:33,f:333,g:4,h:44,i:444,j:5,k:55,l:555,m:6,n:66,o:666,p:7,q:77,r:777,s:7777,t:8,u:88,v:888,w:9,x:99,y:999,z:9999,
$
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2 (97)

I used a single dictionary comprehension:

```
{zip(*[(chr(i)for i in range(65,91))]*3)[i][k]:str(i+2)*(k+1)for k in range(3)for i in range(8)}
```

Unfortunately it's missing the `z` because on number 9 there are 4 letters.

Comment: You could manually add the `z` for a few more characters. Also remove the space between the many `...) for...` to `...)for...`

Comment: `Y` is also missing

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 91 bytes

```
(zipmap(map char(range 97 123))(for[i(range 2 10)r(range 1(get{7 5 9 5}i 4))](repeat r i)))
```

`for` is ideal for generating these kinds of sequences. Output looks like this:

```
{\a (2), \b (2 2), \c (2 2 2), \d (3), ...
```