# Is it an Ordered Word?

Tags: code-golf, string, keyboard

*(inspired by [this post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/53927) over on Puzzling. CAUTION: SPOILERS FOR THAT PUZZLE ARE BELOW.)*

The standard telephone keypad correlates letters to numbers as follows:

```
1 ->
2 -> ABC
3 -> DEF
4 -> GHI
5 -> JKL
6 -> MNO
7 -> PQRS
8 -> TUV
9 -> WXYZ
0 ->
```

A given input word is defined to be an Ordered Word if, when translated to keypad presses using the above, the resulting number is either non-decreasing or non-increasing. In other words, the resultant number cannot both increase *and* decrease.

For example, the word `CAT` translates to `228`, which is non-decreasing, and thus an Ordered Word. However, the word `DOG` is `364`, which both increases and decreases, and thus is not an Ordered Word.

### The challenge

Given a word, output whether or not it's Ordered.

### Input

- A word (not necessarily a dictionary word) consisting of ASCII alphabet (`[A-Z]` or `[a-z]`) letters only, in [any suitable format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Your choice if the input is all uppercase or all lowercase, but it must be consistent.
- The word will be at least 3 characters in length.

### Output

A consistent [truthy/falsey](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/42963) value for whether the input word is Ordered (truthy) or not Ordered (falsey).

### Rules

- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

### Examples

Here are some Ordered Words (i.e., truthy), and there are more on the linked Puzzling puzzle.

```
CAT
TAC
AAA
DEMONS
SKID
LKJONMSRQP
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Here are some non-Ordered Words (i.e., falsey)

```
DOG
GOD
ROSE
COFFEE
JKLMNOGHI
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21327/letters-in-phone-numbers) and [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22875/phone-multi-tap-spelling/22923#22923)  I'm not sure this isn't a dupe, the only change between `abc->t9` and this challenge is checking monotonicity?

Comment: @nmjcman101 Yes, those are related, but there could be other (better?) ways than strictly `abc->t9`.

Comment: That makes sense, I do hope to see something beat that method

Comment: [Also slightly related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93005/is-it-a-bumpy-word)

Comment: Test case request: `AAA`

Comment: Do the output values matter, as long as they're consistent? For example, can we output `0` for true and `1` for false?

Comment: @Shaggy As long as those are truthy/falsey in your language of choice.

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>164</s> <s>148</s> <s>132</s> 77 bytes

*-16 bytes thanks to [Rod's suggestion elsewhere](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136838/is-it-an-ordered-word/136850#comment334875_136848). A frickin' -55 bytes thanks to Arnold Palmer.*

```python
n=[min(int((ord(i)-58)/3.13),9)for i in input()]
print sorted(n)in[n,n[::-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU1da4MwFH3Prwi@mEC70ZXBJvTBaXSt1bTqPsWHoRkNbInElLW/3t3g4XLOuXDOvcPVnrS6mzrdC7zBnudNatP8SkWksoRo0xNJl/cP9HZ9s1rTxSP91gZLLBXMcLaEtmgwkMWjNlb0RFGpGrVQTRAsV207wUWErLkGCAP@TvJH4Nqcxbw7iIvosPuPxKUTg8WMJ8wYbebI8DWOkx@FtY/8OoyAwzAEjlnOiwpMlW1jkH2240VelceDizxFMUvS5@0u2@cFPxzLqn55fXv/@HRNngKn3LVKXjGQiCcJc2bOQ9H/Bw)

Input must be uppercase. Outputs `True` or `False` based on its orderedness.

---

### Explanation

The first line maps each letter to a number.

```python
                               for i in input()   # iterate over the input string
            ord(i)                                # take the ASCII ordinal
                  -58                             # subtract 58
           (         )/3.13                       # divide by 3.13
       int(                )                      # chop off the fractional part
   min(                     ,9)                   # choose the minimum between the number and 9
n=[                                            ]  # assign the resulting list to n
```

This works based on:

```python
          | A   B   C  | D   E   F  | G   H   I  | J   K   L  | M   N   O  | P   Q   R   S  | T   U   V  | W   X   Y   Z
----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+------------+-----------------
ord(x)    | 65  66  67 | 68  69  70 | 71  72  73 | 74  75  76 | 77  78  79 | 80  81  82  83 | 84  85  86 | 87  88  89  90
----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+------------+-----------------
x - 58    | 7   8   9  | 10  11  12 | 13  14  15 | 16  17  18 | 19  20  21 | 22  23  24  25 | 26  27  28 | 29  30  31  32
----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+------------+-----------------
x ÷ 3.13* | 2.2 2.6 2.9| 3.2 3.5 3.8| 4.2 4.5 4.8| 5.1 5.4 5.8| 6.1 6.4 6.7| 7.0 7.3 7.7 7.9| 8.3 8.6 8.9| 9.3 9.6 9.9 10.2
----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+------------+-----------------
int(x)    | 2   2   2  | 3   3   3  | 4   4   4  | 5   5   5  | 6   6   6  | 7   7   7   7  | 8   8   8  | 9   9   9   10
----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+------------+-----------------
min(x, 9) | 2   2   2  | 3   3   3  | 4   4   4  | 5   5   5  | 6   6   6  | 7   7   7   7  | 8   8   8  | 9   9   9   9
```

<sub>*Values are rounded. :P</sub>

The second line outputs if the list of numbers is in ascending or descending order.

```python
print                                             # print whether...
      sorted(n)                                   # n sorted...
               in[n,n[::-1]]                      # is equivalent to n or n reversed
```

Comment: [84 bytes](https://tio.run/##Lcy7DoIwGIbhnatoOrWJxKhxkESTCgU5FigekDBxiCyFFBavHoll@p/h/97hO316sZ/numlBi0ZsaECcC9TLGlVYP550VF1gCvH/5hDj7aHtJahAJ8BYamCQnZjA2MupqZHAnSjERhSGoe/Kcm4RNEkGsbYgI6YCIUTBoiGLuDL3XUsp8D0WhTxN4vX9alrUdm6u5wdhxOIk5dn98Xzl77XCHAWHrYWUcapkMtumq9V86UA8/wA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: Holy cow, that's awesome. Thanks!

Comment: I was going to post it as an answer cause I wrote it before everyone flooded in with answers, but you sniped me :)

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6),  <s>83 ... 71</s>  70 bytes

Returns a boolean.

```js
x=>[...x].every(c=>v&=~(k=x,x=parseInt(c,35)*.32|0||10,x<k?2:x>k),v=3)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

x=>[...x].every(c=>v&=~(k=x,x=parseInt(c,35)*.32|0||10,x<k?2:x>k),v=3)

test = a => a.forEach(s => console.log(f(s) + " for '" + s + "'"))

console.log('[Truthy]')
test(["AAA", "CAT", "TAC", "DEMONS", "SKID", "LKJONMSRQP", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"])

console.log('[Falsy]')
test(["DOG", "GOD", "ROSE", "COFFEE", "JKLMNOGHI"])
```

---

#### How?

**Letter conversion**

We use `parseInt(c, 35)` to convert each letter of the input string to some number in [*10* .. *34*]. Because it's base-35, *"Z"* is converted to `NaN` instead.

The expression `* .32 | 0` maps this number into the interval [*3* .. *10*], leading to 8 correct groups of letters for *"A"* to *"Y"*. We need `|| 10` to get the correct value for *"Z"*.

```
           | A  B  C| D  E  F| G  H  I| J  K  L| M  N  O| P  Q  R  S| T  U  V| W  X  Y   Z
-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+--------+------------
parseInt   |10 11 12|13 14 15|16 17 18|19 20 21|22 23 24|25 26 27 28|29 30 31|32 33 34 NaN
-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+--------+------------
*.32|0||10 | 3  3  3| 4  4  4| 5  5  5| 6  6  6| 7  7  7| 8  8  8  8| 9  9  9|10 10 10  10
```

**Order test**

We keep track of the signs of differences between consecutive numbers into the bitmask ***v***, initially set to 3 (0b11):

- bit #0: cleared when *new_value > previous_value*
- bit #1: cleared when *new_value < previous_value*

The previous value is stored in the same variable ***x*** as the input. This ensures that the first iteration -- where no *previous value* actually exists -- will not clear any bit, because a string containing only letters is neither greater nor less than any number:

```js
('CAT' > 5) === false
('CAT' < 5) === false
```

A word is ordered unless both signs are encountered, which leads to ***v = 0*** and makes `every()` fail.

Comment: Oh, nice trick to get the number of each letter :) I'm torn as to whether I should borrow it or not, as it would mean I'd tie with you, which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>28, 27, 25, 23, 22, 21, 19,</s> 18 bytes

```
_>
O‘ç82ç88:3IṠḟ0E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/ejsv/UcOMw8stjIDYwsrY8@HOBQ93zDdw/f9w95bD7Y@a1vz/7@jkzOXsGMIV4ujM5ejoyOXi6uvvF8wV7O3pwuXj7eXv5xscFBjABVTm4urm7uHp5e3j6@cfEBgUHBIaFh4RGcXl4u/O5e7vwhXkH@zK5ezv5ubqygVRBVQOAA)

This was a lot of fun to write!

Explanation:

```
                # Define a helper link, decrement a if a > b
_               # Subtract
 >              # Boolean greater than
                # Main link:
O               # The ordinals (ASCII points) of the input
 ‘              # Minus one
  ç82           # Decrement if greater than 82
     ç88        # Decrement if greater than 88
        :3      # Divide each number by 3
          I     # Consecutive differences
           Ṡ    # Sign (-1 if < 0, 0 if == 0, and 1 if > 0)
            ḟ0  # Remove all 0's
              E # All elements are equal?
```

Thanks to @ErikTheOutgolfer, @leakynun and @BusinessCat for all saving bytes. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 36 bytes

```
v.•1нJ©½è`ÇHø¹á₂N¸°…ÈáÀ•#Dʒyå}k}¥0‹Ë
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AU0Asv8wNWFiMWX//3Yu4oCiMdC9SsKpwr3DqGDDh0jDuMK5w6HigoJOwrjCsOKApsOIw6HDgOKAoiNEypJ5w6V9a33CpTDigLnDi///c2tpZA)

Comment: You can replace ```.•1нJ©½è`ÇHø¹á₂N¸°…ÈáÀ•#``` by `A•22ā₂•S£`.

Comment: @Adnan rip formatting

Comment: @LeakyNun <s>rip indeed</s> fixed

Comment: @Adnan rip formatting

Comment: @LeakyNun rip indeed

Comment: @Adnan you sure? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f8VHDIiOjI42PmpqArOBDi11OTao8vLQ2u/bQUoNHDTsPd///n1KWAgA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
1Y21K250B-Y{c&m8\dZSu|s2<
```

Input is in upper-case letters. Output is `1` or `0`.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##JYu9DsIgFEZ3H0QmE0ti4uBC@bOlcFvAKo2DRkc7qZO@O17icr5vOGe@vh75kqtEK0M363qVPrflvD3fp/D@Pukui5gJZ5EsSGQcyRhDCmnBBTzBNAKnMy04G/zQF6XmQiq9b1rTWQf94EM8jMdTmkoJGqmhVB6CxOGglCzn72NIfg)

#### Explanation

```
1Y2      % Push 'ABC...XYZ'
1        % Push 1
K        % Push 4
250B     % Push 250 in binary, that is, [1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]
-        % Subtract (from 4, element-wise): gives [3 3 3 3 3 4 1 4]
Y{       % Convert to cell array, splitting into chunks of those lengths
c        % Convert to char matrix. Gives a 4-column matrix. Chunks of length 3
         % are right-padded with a space
&m       % Implicit input. Push (linear) index of membership in char matrix
8\       % Modulo 8. Converts linear index into 0-based row index
d        % Consecutive differences
ZS       % Sign
u        % Unique
|        % Absolute value
s        % Sum
2<       % Less than 2? Implicit display
```

Comment: Appropriate score for an alphabetic challenge :P

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Not anymore :-D

Answer (score 3):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>22 21 19</s> 18 bytes

```
±S€Ẋ▲`Ṫo±≤"DGJMPTW
```

Returns `1` for truthy inputs, `0` for falsy ones.
Inputs must be in uppercase.
Passes all test cases.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkPuoqfHQtv@HNgY/alrzcFfXo2mbEh7uXJV/aOOjziVKLu5evgEh4f///3d2DOEKcXTmcnR05HJx9fX3C@YK9vZ04fLx9vL38w0OCgzgcnRydnF1c/fw9PL28fXzDwgMCg4JDQuPiIzicvF353L3d@EK8g925XL2d3NzdeWCqAIqBwA)

### Explanation

```
±S€Ẋ▲`Ṫo±≤"DGJMPTW  Implicit input x, e.g. "CAT"
     `Ṫo±≤"DGJMPTW  This part transforms x into a "canonical form" corresponding to the numpad digits
     `Ṫ             Table with flipped arguments
       o±≤          on sign of less-than-or-equal
                    (In Husk, ≤ returns extra information we don't want, so we take sign of the result to get 0 or 1.)
          "DGJMPTW  of this string and x.
                    This gives, for each char in x, a bit array of comparisons with the chars in the string:
                    y = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1,0]]
   Ẋ▲               Maxima of adjacent pairs: [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1,0]]
 S€                 1-based index in y as sublist: 2
±                   Sign: 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 60 bytes

```python
a=[3681/ord(c)for c in input()]
print sorted(a)in[a,a[::-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU1BboQwDLzziogLILVabStVFdIet9e99IY4uImBLBBnndCFfp46YmTNjKUZ229xIPe2R97qTAmeg51QffOCx56AK2qV5/kOl@b94/N8IjalrjpipZV1Mn6JZdVmnq2LKhBHNCVU1jXwAk1dv57bdpcDGa4afVTX29eVmfh44SGEvdAQi6yIoIUBQNjgTC6ICaM1ItN4JzcHfvgU@dEGu36w93GaHfkHh7j8PtftLzWpF@4ptZgCimjqOkzmyEux@Ac)

Accepts input in lowercase.

#### How it works

⌊3681/*x*⌋ decreases from

- 38 to 37 at *x* ≈ 96.8684210526, before `a`;
- 37 to 36 at *x* ≈ 99.4864864865, between `c` and `d`;
- 36 to 35 at *x* ≈ 102.25, between `f` and `g`;
- 35 to 34 at *x* ≈ 105.171428571, between `i` and `j`;
- 34 to 33 at *x* ≈ 108.264705882, between `l` and `m`;
- 33 to 32 at *x* ≈ 111.545454545, between `o` and `p`;
- 32 to 31 at *x* ≈ 115.03125, between `s` and `t`;
- 31 to 30 at *x* ≈ 118.741935484, between `v` and `w`;
- 30 to 29 at *x* ≈ 122.7, after `z`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>107</s> <s>97</s> <s>95</s> <s>92</s> <s>88</s> 85 bytes

Works with mixed-case strings. Returns `1` for truthy or `0` for falsey.

```js
s=>(s=(a=[...s].map(c=>(parseInt(c,36)-3)/3.13%10|0||9))+"")==a.sort()|s==a.reverse()
```

- 10 bytes saved thanks to [Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47120/rod).

---

### Try It

```js
o.innerText=(f=
s=>(s=(a=[...s].map(c=>(parseInt(c,36)-3)/3.13%10|0||9))+"")==a.sort()|s==a.reverse()
)(i.value="Cat")
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o>
```

Comment: `Math.min((parseInt(c,36)-3)/3.13|0,9)` instead `"2..9"[parseInt(c,36)-10]` to save some bytes

Comment: Thanks, @Rod; very nice. I'll have to file that away for future use.

Comment: [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY9da8IwFIbv9yuCOEyYzZTC2MAUun6t1jba1H25DUNXh@Ka0hRvrL@9i4t3z3vOeR84O37gMq@3VWOU4rvoNqSTxIKSQE5WGGP5iX95BXM1q3gti7BsYD4075BholsTj83r8agdte0DQjf3yOJYirqBir/khOO6OBSqdM5dLkop9gXeix@4ugKg59hZb3iGzHY0uF5ME6aZRaGraRZNaRKzdDHX2X50XM8PnsJpNIsTOl@kLFs@v7y@vav9v4YG@jKgF0VKmafJob7vXVj3lUhF/SYHxALr/pGfgGEYFugfN5Cj0xrhndiWcPBRDhDq/gA).

Comment: Thanks, @ThePirateBay, but,sadly, that fails for input `AAA`.

Answer (score 2):

### C++, <s>375</s> <s>199</s> <s>195</s> 194 bytes

Thanks to Shaggy's JavaScript answer :
-5 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<string>
int o(std::string a){std::string m="22233344455566677778889999";for(auto&b:a)b=m[b-65];int j=1,i=0,d=0;for(;j<a.size();++j){if(a[j]>a[j-1])++i;if(a[j]<a[j-1])++d;}return!(i*d);}
```

Comment: Can you move the `int j=1,i=0,d=0` to the for loop?

Comment: @Zacharý Since `i` and `d` are used outside of the loop block, i can't

Comment: `i==0||d==0` ==> `i*d==0`.

Comment: Would `!(i*d)` work? (removing the space after `return`)

Comment: @Zacharý Yes, it works

Comment: @Zacharý miscalculations

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 30 bytes

```
A3 8×Ƶ0+S£¹δåā>‚øε`*}.«+¥0K0‹Ë
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT4Awf8wNWFiMWX//0EzIDjDl8a1MCtTwqPCuc60w6XEgT7igJrDuM61YCp9LsKrK8KlMEsw4oC5w4v//2NvZmZlZQ)

-1 thanks to [Magic Octopus Urn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59376/magic-octopus-urn).

Comment: Did you use `¥0K0.SË` because `¥0‹Ë` isn't correct? I can't tell if the `0.S` is needed.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn In fact `¥0K0‹Ë` seems to work.

Comment: Yeah, if you're removing the 0's it should; in my answer I'm not sure it works.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I'm removing the 0s since otherwise there will be false negatives. Your answer might behave differently though.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>29</s> <s>27</s> <s>25</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia/blob/master/codepage.md)

```
ċ⟨):“QX’>¦Σ⁻3/⟩¦o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9nYWlh///Ei@KfqCk64oCcUVjigJk@wqbOo@KBuzMv4p@pwqZv//9DQVQ)

#### Explanation

```
ċ                  Turn the input into a list of code points
 ⟨            ⟩¦   Map this block to each code point:
  )                 Increment it
   :                Copy it
    “QX’            Push [81 88]
        >¦          Check if the code point is greater than each of [81 88]
          Σ         Sum the results
           ⁻        Subtract from the code point
            3/      Integer divide the result by 3
                o  Check if the resulting list is in sorted order (increasing or decreasing)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> 17 bytes

#### Code

```
A•22ā₂•Sās×J‡Ô¥dË
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f8VHDIiOjI42PmpqArOAjjcWHp3s9alh4eMqhpSmHu///T04sAQA) or [Verify all test cases!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9zaGVZ5X/HRw2LjIyOND5qagKygo80Fh@e7vWoYeHhKYeWphzu/l@pdHi/lcLh/Uo6/5MTS7hKEpO5EhMTuVJSc/PzirmKszNTuHKys/LzcouLCgu4EpOSU1LT0jMys7JzcvPyCwqLiktKy8orKqu4UvLTudLzU7iK8otTuZLz09JSU7kgqoDKAQ)

#### Explanation

```
A                   # Push the lowercase alphabet
 •22ā₂•             # Push the number 33333434
       S            # Split into an array
        ā           # Get the range of indices [1 .. length]
         s×         # Swap and string multiply
           J        # Join that array
            ‡       # Transliterate
```

This now essentially maps the following letters to the following numbers:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
11122233344455566667778888
```

```
             Ô      # Remove consecutive duplicates
              ¥     # Compute the delta's of the list
               d    # Check if the number is greater or equal to 0
                Ë   # Check if all elements are the same
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](http://pyth.readthedocs.io), 23 bytes

One of my first non-trivial Pyth answer! Saved 6 bytes thanks to @LeakyNun. The initial solution is below.

```
/{_BKmhS,9/a58Cd3.13zSK
```

[Test Suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2F%7B_BKmhS%2C9%2Fa58Cd3.13zSK&input=DOG%0AGOD%0AROSE%0ACOFFEE%0AJKLMNOGHI&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=CAT%0ATAC%0AAAA%0ADEMONS%0ASKID%0ALKJONMSRQP%0AABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%0ADOG%0AGOD%0AROSE%0ACOFFEE%0AJKLMNOGHI&debug=0)

## [Pyth](http://pyth.readthedocs.io), 29 bytes

```
KmhS+9]/-Cd58 3.13w|qKSKqK_SK
```

[Test Suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=KmhS%2B9%5D%2F-Cd58+3.13w%7CqKSKqK_SK&input=DOG%0AGOD%0AROSE%0ACOFFEE%0AJKLMNOGHI&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=CAT%0ATAC%0AAAA%0ADEMONS%0ASKID%0ALKJONMSRQP%0AABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%0ADOG%0AGOD%0AROSE%0ACOFFEE%0AJKLMNOGHI&debug=0)

---

## Explanation

```
/{_BKmhS,9/a58Cd3.13zSKQ - The Q means evaluated input and is implicit at the end

 {                      - Deduplicate
  _                     - Reverse
   B                    - Bifurcate, Create a two-element list, [B, A(B)]
    K                   - Variable with auto-assignement to:
     m              z    - Map over the input:
      hS                  - Minimum (first element of sorted list)
        ,                 - Create a two-element list, [A, B] with these elements:
         9                  - The numeric literal 9
          /                 - The integer division of:
           a58Cd              - The absolute difference between 58 and ord(current_element)   
                3.13          - The numeric literal 3.13
                    SK   - K sorted
/                     Q  - Count the occurrences of the input in [K, K[::-1]]
```

Comment: [23 bytes](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2F%7B_BKmhS%2C9%2Fa58Cd3.13zSK&input=DOG%0AGOD%0AROSE%0ACOFFEE%0AJKLMNOGHI&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=CAT%0ATAC%0AAAA%0ADEMONS%0ASKID%0ALKJONMSRQP%0AABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%0ADOG%0AGOD%0AROSE%0ACOFFEE%0AJKLMNOGHI&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 65 bytes

```
T`_ADGJMPTW`d
}T`L`_L
(.)\1*
$1$*1<
(1+)<(?!\1)
$1>
1

^(<*|>*)>$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcq7CsIwAAXQ/f6FUCGNIGQvlZiksc@0TbQqxUbQwcVBHPXbY8H1cF739@N5DUtCtA/OT1zqom7d4G/4Ol/5qQJZxyOjiFhEWQLCVnFCNouRxTOlYMCFJPST0jiNQhDcwXEBzjmkqk1jYctcoioL09S271rwrZAq07u8KKu6MW3XW7c/DMfTGdJoaCPRG6sgTJYphf@a@w8) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
T`_ADGJMPTW`d
```

Change the first letter on each key to a digit. (This is off by 1 but that doesn't matter for an ascending/descending check. On the other hand, zeros would make my life more difficult, so I left one filler character in.)

```
}T`L`_L
```

Shuffle all the remaining letters up 1 and repeat until they've all been converted to digits.

```
(.)\1*
$1$*1<
```

Convert the digits into unary, but only once per run of identical digits. The unary values are seprated with a `<`...

```
(1+)<(?!\1)
$1>
```

... but if the LHS turns out to be greater than the RHS, correct the `<` to `>`.

```
1
```

Delete the `1`s which are no longer necessary.

```
^(<*|>*)>$
```

Check that the word is ordered. (The trailing `>` comes from the last digit which always compares greater than the empty space following it.)

Comment: That's pretty cool. Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
ÇÍžq÷8
7:Ô¥dË
```

Whenever I see a numpad question, I have to make a pi-based answer.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9vc2FiaWX//8OHw43FvnHDtzgKNzrDlMKlZMOL//9hYmRjZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5eg) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##Jcq7DcIwEADQ/qaIUkMNoiCzXPzDceyLPwSM6CkQHSswAx0FFnMZJF79KGKvRT3PuWub5bZpu1zLpdw@L1@ea1htyv394OVaF5VhgoQMEBG4sOQiRKM5jGYgZ2PwE2DPuJBqpwczWkeTDzHt58Mxn4CTAkUcAkUBjKQUAv7r178)

```
Ç                    # ASCII code of each letter in the input
 Í                   # add 2
  žq÷                # divide by pi
     8 7:            # replace 8 with 7
         Ô           # remove duplicates
          ¥          # deltas
           d         # each >= 0 ?
            Ë        # are all elements equal?
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 32 bytes

```
“¢Ç⁺H’D0ẋj1œṗØA⁸=€×"€9Ḋ¤Fḟ0Iḟ0ṠE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVUAqv9qZWxsef//4oCcwqLDh@KBukjigJlEMOG6i2oxxZPhuZfDmEHigbg94oKsw5ci4oKsOeG4isKkRuG4nzBJ4bifMOG5oEX/w4fFkuG5mP//Q09GRkVF)

Comment: RIP compression

Comment: @LeakyNun The compressed number is actually `32222323` so it saves just 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>143</s> <s>147</s> <s>148</s> <s>149</s> 130 bytes

```python
def g(s,f=lambda c:min(int((ord(c)-58)/3.13),9)):x=[f(a)-f(b)for a,b in zip(s,s[1:])];return any(t<0for t in x)*any(t>0for t in x)
```

Best I can do for now. Crude function turns the letter into the number based off of ascii code. There are definitely some improvements to be made. 0 is truthy, 1 is falsey (sorry). Saved 10 bytes thanks to Rod, another 3 thanks to Mr. Xcoder.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9Nb4JAEIbv/IoNp50G2xrSpKW1CeWrirDK0k/jAUQsSV3Iukbtn6cMvXjoXN4nkzfPZJqT@qqF2bbFuiQbujPK0Xe2zYuMrKxtJWglFKW1LOgKBje3cGVeDk0w7gCs42hR0gwGJc2hrCXJjJxUgvxUTWfZLYbWEpb3cq32UpBMnKh6uMaawtIRLvrV4/mqRT4gU92xU90gemo7GLZtY7hexGKOxMOxizkNJyyOeDKf9bUnx/X84Hk8CadRzGbzhKcvr2/vH586WBrpppH4z4YeADTt7JzLAhQErLcmjHuYDvN9r6c/YWf@R9T@Ag)

Comment: you can use `x=[f(a)-f(b)for a,b in zip(s,s[1:])]` to save some bytes

Comment: also, `min(int((ord(c)-58)/3.13),9)` is a shorter way to convert the char

Comment: [140 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY1Lb4JAFEb3/IoJG@9tINa6o9WE8qqijAJ9WMOC8iqJHcyAUX89ZaYbF53NObn5cuZ47b4bNu37vChJBa1Wzg7pz1eeksyAhueQof6gQzYfhSPE8XgqfTe4cZntS2j3dYK6pD5JsGw4qUnNCE9ZVcBEOxQMWsTkkRfdiTOSsit0T/di14ndBe/kaX576oWfhYNqmbGqETU2LQHTNAVsZ02DSFjkL2zBlb@kwToKtxs5e7Zsx/VeFkt/tQ7oZhtG8evb@8fuU0VDIcM78pp1UMEZUVFuvrOpJwIeldWQRo6gRV3XkfYXHMr/hPpf)

Comment: @Rod Thanks! Very helpful.

Comment: You'll need to swap your outputs around in order for this to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>111</s> 103 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to @Arnold Palmer:no `lower()` needed*

- Takes uppercase letters as input.

```python
lambda x:sorted(f(x))in[f(x),f(x)[::-1]]
f=lambda x:['22233344455566677778889999'[ord(i)-65]for i in x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY47b4MwFIV3foU3g0SG8gpFyuDySkLAgEn6cD2kohBLCUSEgfx6iqnEGe53hvNJ9/7sL22jjfXme7yebz/lGQzOo@3631Ku5EFReEMFVXGo46xeGJOqzTKlUNM0XdcNwzBN07Ks9RTbtl@nQNp2pcyVlWWyqu0AB7wBAxuXTqGLCqhKsECuAEJIwPNjnBDRSLTzBA/RHicxybN0nr25nh@E290@OsQJTrOcFMfT@8fn12zjUCDEs5lj4gu6OAj8uf1Lkw0l5tw73vSgnp4c/wA)

Comment: You can remove the `.lower()` since the input can be in whatever case you specify.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 133 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;q=>{var u=q.Select(c=>(int)((c-58)/3.13));var z=u.Zip(u.Skip(1),(a,b)=>a-b);return!(z.Any(d=>d<0)&z.Any(d=>d>0));};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVJtT6swGP3eX/FcYm7aZOO6GBMjQoLs5bo35pjvMaYrVRtn2WjRKOG3TxBhcj6056RPz9OTp0y1WRTzbaKEfILgQ2n@aqHfyhwLubEQkvSVqzVlHGYzb/DQQSliK6oUrBHkSL/XAkpTLRi8RSKECRUSk/poV1Sgn0h2onSc92rBMopWDvhxyGMegr3d2E76RmNI7I0Z8BVnGjPbwUJqgjFrHx6Rfwdm54AQq6j6tBPzVqxxYgYv@dYhLUxbS2I7tL0kVsx1Ess/@NN05QcObSc82Sd/d8rZz20ya9t4Xfmwu3tYcKUZVVyBDZK/392jMobhuQujVdKF61XUdd2KdnsTfxpUKhiddSs@Hg396SSYn8/qa6det9cf/D8bjsaTqT87nweLi8ur65vb2s0fVHTg105zP@hV3PP7/V6tSqPc0UCZ1Yj2mE@csmfAZUbQeUIQcpeUNMqbUyvgRVJFK25exULz/H9wvGekhUt2DOnPDHGhSWaQZu8M7ViWbb8A)

I feel like there's some room to save, but C# is not a concise language so maybe not. Ungolfed:

```cs
bool Ordered(string word){

    IEnumerable<int> keys = word.Select(character => (int)((character - 58)/3.13)); 
    // convert characters to keypad number

    IEnumerable<int> differences = keys.Zip(keys.Skip(1), (a, b)=> a-b); 
    // difference between consecutive elements

    return !(differences.Any(diff => diff<0) & differences.Any(diff => diff>0)); 
    // false if both positive and negative differences exist
}
```

In particular I think there's a shorter way to express the final check for validity, possibly a way to inline it with the `Zip`. Finding a way to express the `Zip` without needing temporary storage for the `Skip` would also save something, but I doubt there's something more concise for that.

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, <s>37</s> <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```
q{_"SVZY"#g-i3/}%_$_W%](e=g
```

[Try it Online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7B_%22SVZY%22%23g-i3%2F%7D%25_%24_W%25%5D(e%3Dg&input=COFFEE)

Of course the ugly version ends up being shorter...

```
q{        e# For each character in string...
_"SVZY"#g e# Get index of that character in "SVZY". Signum that. (returns 1 or 0 if inside string, -1 if not.)
-i3/      e# Subtract value from character (i.e 'Z' becomes 'Y', 'F' becomes 'G'). Convert to int. Integer divide by 3. (this is just how the math works out for proper mapping of characters to phone digits.)
}%
_$_W%]    e# Put mapped string, sorted version, and reverse sorted version in array.
(         e# Pop mapped string from array onto stack.
e=        e# Count occurences of mapped string in array.
g         e# Signum.
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, <s>92</s> 66 bytes

```
ΔList(int(seq(inString("BC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQRSTUV WXYZ",sub(Ans,I,1))/4,I,1,length(Ans
0≤min(Ansmax(Ans
```

Converts each character in the string to an integer from 0 to 7, and takes the difference between each consecutive element; then checks whether the minimum and maximum differences have the same sign (or either is 0).

Comment: I think `ΔList(int(4^-1seq(inString("DEF GHI JKL MNO PQRSTUV WXYZ",sub(Ans,I,1))+3,I,1,length(Ans` saves one byte.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 7, <s>98+1 95+1</s> 84+1 bytes

a golfed port of [Arnauld´s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136845/55735).

```php
for(;$c=ord($argn[$i]);$v|=$i++?$p>$k?2:$p<$k:0,$p=$k)$k=($c-58)*.32%10?:9;echo$v<3;
```

accepts uppercase; empty output for falsy, `1` for truthy.

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f26cfc8142770f319d40b92201611518aecbbcad).

original post:

```php
for(;$c=$argn[$i++];$p?$a[]=$p<=>$k:0,$p=$k)$k=(ord($c)-58)/3.13-($c>Y)|0;echo min($a)*max($a)>=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>183 169 153</s> 117 bytes

```c
#define a(b)(int)fmin(*(b c)/3.2,27)
d(char*c){int r=1,p=1;for(;1<strlen(c);)r&=a()<=a(1+),p&=a()>=a(++);return r|p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZNNT8JAEIbv/IoGo9nlQwMeTCyYlH5ZoCzQ8hkvpVAkgdoseEL@unWgRHYzcrCHTZ7Jk503O9OwvAzDNL2ZL6JVvFACMqNkFe9otFnFpEBmSkgfHu@rpeoTzc1J@B7wQkj3YCi8Xikl9YoafXCiVmrbHV8vYhJSlfK7ekBoDY5KkZaSE73AUSxSlS92nzxW@FeiHtLjNZsAGtF9ToEv4VCJSF7X/Gfldv4W50vK/IR5SlVJ8TVdVACRommaqAAixTBd1vFEK6sg0Ws5hqgdGUntVpN1XK/f64rqpYoTNnTDtOxXp9lqux3W7fU9fzAcjSdTKfhVC104nYxHw4F/bAY9obPzalumoTekl7hu/ZUwa58lyEJkOc5RznHOiS7ZhfT/vgHPidnSkJiNFJtJAwJEim5IOwOIFMu2RAUQKU7TERVAvAhuW9oAt40U1mWiAoh3zpc2ExApw9FQVADxBKfyXzDFQ@4zzxSdI@PHY5ZlSlpWQWI2W5iz6P4WT/oh/Q6jdbDcpuX15gc)

Old solution:

```c
#define a(b)(int)((int)(b*.32-17.6)*.9)
d(char*c){int l=~-strlen(c),i=0,r=1,p=1;for(;i<l;++i)r&=a(c[i])<=a(c[i+1]),p&=a(c[l-i])<=a(c[l-i-1]);return r+p;}
```

Saved 8 bytes thanks to ThePirateBay.

Old old solution:

```c
d(char*c){char*a="22233344455566677778889999";int l=strlen(c)-1,i=0,r=1,p=1;for(;i<l;++i){if(a[c[i]-65]>a[c[i+1]-65])r=0;if(a[c[l-i]-65]>a[c[l-i-1]-65])p=0;}return r+p;}
```

Old old old solution:

```c
d(char*c){char*a="22233344455566677778889999";int l=strlen(c);int i,r=1,p=1;for(;i<l-1;++i)if(a[c[i]-65]>a[c[i+1]-65])r=0;for(i=l-1;i>0;--i)if(a[c[i]-65]>a[c[i-1]-65])p=0;return r+p;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>73 69</s>  57 bytes

***-12 bytes** by using @anders-kaseorg's `3681/code` conversion.*

```sh
for c (${(s::)1})((y=3681/#c,A|=y<p,D|=p&&p<y,p=y,!D|!A))
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxNT4NAAETv/Ipp2sNuQrXioRFLzMoCthS2BfzqwaRhl0BiIOn2IIq/HQledE6TeS/zqcu@IJQYWp0x/@ilYy2NojkhB5l9EW3b9OqbEtI603x@s7hbvJFpfnl9YVHbWpqsc9rV0eSdI1eteXSk05oT3k0YpT01xh@NqobLMmTMBWMM3ItEnCIN1xzbcCPiKE32O7B7l3t@8LDehNsoFrt9kmaPT88vrwdwESAQHIlIPbjC9z0Pv9aggx3YLWRjYEhVoMBMj/1cqhoqL5thQKXRnKQ6KTky9a7VXxaL7B8vKkM2tep/AA)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxNT4NAAETv/Ipp2jS7CWqtByOWmJVdsKWwLeBXD15gCSQGCOuFir8dsV50TpN5L3PUxZATSoa8bpGCzD6Jtix6@UUJ6expenazuFu8kWl6cXW@pNby2mS93a0ak/d2M583q85s7M6c8H7CKB2oYfwcaZQVHJYgYQ4YY@AikGGM2F9zbP2NDIM42u/A7h0uXO9hvfG3QSh3@yhOHp@eX14P4NKDJzkiGQs40nWFwK816mAHdousNjCmzJFjpk/9o1AVVFrU44BSo24z1arsxNS7Vn9ZKJN/PC@NrK7U8A0)</s>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzNTsMwEITveYqpqCpbioQqJITa5lCpZ7jwAsZeJ24Sr2uHH4fw7CGUC@xpNN83O6ZmtkKK2XKEhlh/irTbye2XFCJXd/cP29sbXR6nKh9CeZqqsNmEQy5DlcvVaVodpZxlUfyME5yHVgMGpaGUgqGefUJqnUHXntn3KV4C1Is2ZOvGnduu9xwuMQ2vb@8feYThGjUbRE4EzdYS4ddadKhR7RelwHLOwmKdrnloyIN0w0sBl8DRUCRzZdQtn/6wx6fnf9y6wrCn@Rs)

A few things we abuse:

- `((statement,statement,...))` is a sequence of *arithmetic* expressions which returns truthy if the last statement is non-zero.
- The return value of a loop is the return value of the last statement in a loop.
- Arithmetic operator precedences were pretty nice to us, as <s>only one pair of</s> **no** parentheses were used. One byte could be saved if `!` bound less tightly than `&`.
- Unset parameters expand to `0` in arithmetic expansions.
- <s>The function we use to map to the keypad number is `CODE / 3.2 - 18` (with a special case for `Z`), but</s> since we only need the *change* between codes, we don't do the linear adjustment.

```sh
for c (${(s::)1})           # split into characters
    (( y = #c-90 ? 0^(#c/3.2) : 27,   # this sets y to the keypad number + 18
       A |= y < p,          # set the A flag if we detect it is not ascending
       D |= p && p < y,     # ditto descending, don't compare on first iteration
       p = y,               # save the current character
       !D | !A              # return false if D and A are both set
    ))
```

2 bytes can be saved if the truthy/falsey values can be swapped.